# How to suppress warnings in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-construction, compiler-warnings, xcode5

In Xcode 5, is there any way to suppress warnings such as unused variables for number of files? Particularly latest Box2D 2.2.1 produces some warnings which are annoying but harmless.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Select the project in the navigator, then select the target from the list. Select the Build Phases tab, then expand the Compile Sources phase. The Compiler Flags column is where you specify per-file compiler flags. Enter -Wno- to negate a warning. e.g.: -Wno-unused-parameter

Comment: I like this more specific way

Answer (score 19):

You can add a compiler flag `-w` for each affected .m file you want silenced, in the build phases for your app's target, under "Compile Sources."

Comment: Is this possible to do for xcassets that are in the copy bundle resources