# Ignore specific warning in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, ios8, xcode6

I want Xcode to ignore the following warning:

> "Automatic Preferred Max Layout Width is not available on iOS versions
>   prior to 8.0."

Is there a way to tell Xcode not to show this specific warning?

Comment: Hope this helps you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25398312/automatic-preferred-max-layout-width-is-not-available-on-ios-versions-prior-to-8

Comment: I know the reason for this warning - I just want Xcode to ignore it

Comment: There is `--warnings` flag for [ibtool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ibtool.1.html), I don't know how to remove this flag from the command.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18965782/how-to-suppress-warnings-in-xcode

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to your project file in Xcode and select Build Settings. Ensure all build settings are showed and it is Combined. Scroll down until you see a section called "Interface Builder Storyboard Compiler - Options". There should be a show warnings section for that, just set it to No and recompile and the warning should go away. If it does not just restart Xcode and then the warning should be gone.

[image: Example]

Comment: I don't want to remove all warnings - just a specific warning

Comment: @godmoney this will only stop showing warnings for the interface builder. It will carry on showing warnings for the code editor. To suppress specific warnings will be more tricky.

Comment: I still want to see other warnings from the IB

Comment: Ok I will try to find out, may I ask why you are getting this warning in the first place? And why not make your project build for iOS 8?

Comment: We are still supporting iOS 7 - and that's why we are still building for iOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

If you find out the way to remove `--warnings` flag for [ibtool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ibtool.1.html) then you might ignore all the warnings from the `nib` file.

The workaround is to build this storyboard for iOS8.0

[image]

**NOTE:**
Though it removes the warning but I have never run the app on iOS7 and I don't know what's the impact of this change.

Also do notify me if you find a better solution

Comment: Chances are on iOS7 some UI layouts are broken which is the reason for the warning to begin with.

Answer (score -1):

You should follow below steps :

**Select Project Build Settings -> Interface Builder Storyboard Compiler - Options -> Show Warnings -> set to "NO"**

Note that if you wish to clear existing warnings you can clean your project using Shift+⌘+k

you can do it by code but don't know for the storyboard working

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wwarning-flag"
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Wouldn't this also stop other warning in IB? Not just this specific one?

Comment: I don't want to remove all warnings - just a specific warning